# Sharepoint 2013-Form/View limitation on custom list schema

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server

We are trying to add a lot of forms to a list by adding in its schema.xml this:

Forms>

Form Type="EditForm" Url="Test.aspx"                 SetupPath="features\$SharePoint.Feature.DeploymentPath$\CustomList\Forms\Test.aspx" UseLegacyForm="TRUE" WebPartZoneID="Main" Default="FALSE" UseDefaultListFormWebPart="FALSE"/>

/Forms>

There shouldn't be a limit for the Form tag, but after like 90 forms we can't add anymore and when we try to enable the feature with the list we get an error while activating the list feature.
We also tried to add the forms by creating a module with the forms, and referencing them in the content types, the problem is that the file is not recognized as a form and therefore is not shown as a form should, with the ribbon and so on. Is there anyway to increase this limit or other alternative solution?

Comment: Its not the columns, its the list forms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was resolved by adding a Module to the list instance, and add the forms like files.

Them add the variables do became a form.